# Where is the default audio visualisation in the ffplay.c?

Tags: ffmpeg

When you play audio with `ffplay`, or video with the `-vn` flag, `ffplay` displays a spectrogram. I'm trying to find which part of the `ffplay.c` code is responsible for that.

I want to enable/disable video with a press of a button, and also change the audio visualisation to something else.

I suppose the filter that does that is called `showspectrum`, but I don't see it anywhere. And I can't find any interesting `avfilter_graph_create_filter` either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `video_display`, there's

```
if (is->audio_st && is->show_mode != SHOW_MODE_VIDEO)
    video_audio_display(is);
```

And `video_audio_display` generates the spectrogram.